# Dataframe column: to find local maxima

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, max

In the below dataframe the column "CumRetperTrade" is a column which consists of a few vertical vectors (=sequences of numbers) separated by zeros. (= these vectors correspond to non-zero elements of column "Portfolio").
I would like to find the local maxima of every non-zero vector contained in column "CumRetperTrade"
To be precise, I would like to transform (using vectorization - or other - methods) column "CumRetperTrade" to the column "PeakCumRet" (desired result) which provides maxima for every vector contained in column "CumRetperTrade" its local max value. The numeric example is below. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Portfolio": [1, 1, 1, 0 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
"CumRetperTrade": [3, 2, 1, 0 , 0, 0, 4, 2, 1],
"PeakCumRet": [3, 3, 3, 0 , 0, 0, 4, 4, 4]})
df1

Portfolio   CumRetperTrade  PeakCumRet
1           3               3
1           2               3
1           1               3
0           0               0
0           0               0
0           0               0
1           4               4
1           2               4
1           1               4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
df1['PeakCumRet'] = (df1.groupby(df1['Portfolio'].ne(df1['Portfolio'].shift()).cumsum())
                     ['CumRetperTrade'].transform('max')
                     )
```

Output:

```
   Portfolio  CumRetperTrade  PeakCumRet
0          1               3           3
1          1               2           3
2          1               1           3
3          0               0           0
4          0               0           0
5          0               0           0
6          1               4           4
7          1               2           4
8          1               1           4
```